# Tape data for FX pairs on google

Tags: market-data

I use google API to get intraday tape data (volume delayed by 15 min) for stocks and ETFs:
http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?i=60&p=5d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v&df=cpct&q=SPY

Is there a similar API that will give the tape data for FX trades for major pairs?

Comment: The link does not work - what granularity do you need? tick data?

Comment: The link returns `not found`… Did you mean https://www.google.com/finance#stockscreener ?

Comment: The link works for me...yes i am looking for tick data